# Swipe the screen works, but pressing the tab does not work android tab-layout

Tags: android

Swipe the screen works, but pressing the tab does not work android tab-layout

I want the tab to work by pressing, not just by Swipe, as you see in the video

[Video For App](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12GLWtHNaRB7S-Q9vhf4qzSjpidhqCun6/view?usp=sharing)

MainActivity

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("احجزلي").setIcon(R.drawable.facebook));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("جايلك"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this, tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

ViewPageAdapter.Class

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Context context;
int totalTabs;

public ViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, int totalTabs){
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    this.totalTabs = totalTabs;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return totalTabs;
}

public Fragment getItem(int position){
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            BookingTabFragment bookingTabFragment = new BookingTabFragment();
            return bookingTabFragment;
        case 1:
            ComingTabFragment comingTabFragment = new ComingTabFragment();
            return comingTabFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it helped can you please upvote the answer as well, it helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **addOnTabSelectedListener** and on the Tab selected set the current item of viewPager like below.

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
        @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
    
    });
```

Comment: If it helped can you please upvote the answer as well, it helps me.